# How to drop column names with similar column names?

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

I would like to drop columns that have *similar* column names.
What I mean by this is that I have list of survey questions and often at times the same question shows up on the column header but one will have have a punctuation mark and another will not have punctuation mark. Some questions have a question mark at the end, and the same one will have a punctuation mark at the end or even a blank space. I want to make these column headers consistent and remove any duplicate ones showing up.

**This is my current code:**

```
 'import excel file'
df = pd.read_csv(ExlPathName)

print(df)


'replace all "." characters in the first row with " " '
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(".", " ")
print(df)
    

'Using DataFrame.drop_duplicates() to keep first duplicate row'
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

print(df2)
```

An example would be:
*What do you think about this company?* may show up again as *What do you think about this company.*
or:
*I would recommend this company to a friend* may show up again as *I would recommend this company to a friend.*

```py
> Out[1]:
```

| Test1? | Test1. | Test2 | Test2. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 | 8 | 8 |
| 4 | 4 | 9 | 9 |

Comment: Hi, could you provide please an example dataframe with a couple of column names in order for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added a sample output that I want to merge